# Plot data from a LaTeX table

Tags: tables, plot

I have a table in LaTeX format. I would like to plot a few figures using this data, having the five frequencies (125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000) on the horizontal axis, and the absorption coefficient between 0 and 1 on the vertical axis.

Is there a tool that supports LaTeX tables as data to plot from?

```
    \begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l | l | l | l |}
\hline
Floor Materials & 
    125 Hz & 
    250 Hz & 
    500 Hz & 
1000 Hz & 
2000 Hz & 
4000 Hz \\ \hline


concrete or tile & 
0.01 & 
0.01 & 
0.015 & 
0.02 & 
0.02 & 
0.02 \\ 

linoleum/vinyl tile on concrete & 
0.02 & 
0.03 & 
0.03 & 
0.03 & 
0.03 & 
0.02 \\ 

wood on joists & 
0.15 & 
0.11 & 
0.10 & 
0.07 & 
0.06 & 
0.07 \\ 

parquet on concrete & 
0.04 & 
0.04 & 
0.07 & 
0.06 & 
0.06 & 
0.07 \\ 

carpet on concrete & 
0.02 & 
0.06 & 
0.14 & 
0.37 & 
0.60 & 
0.65 \\ 

carpet on foam & 
0.08 & 
0.24 & 
0.57 & 
0.69 & 
0.71 & 
0.73 \\ 

\hline
Seating Materials & 
    125 Hz & 
    250 Hz & 
    500 Hz & 
1000 Hz & 
2000 Hz & 
4000 Hz \\ \hline 


fully occupied - fabric upholstered & 
0.60 & 
0.74 & 
0.88 & 
0.96 & 
0.93 & 
0.85 \\ 

occupied wooden pews & 
0.57 & 
0.61 & 
0.75 & 
0.86 & 
0.91 & 
0.86 \\ 

empty - fabric upholstered & 
0.49 & 
0.66 & 
0.80 & 
0.88 & 
0.82 & 
0.70 \\ 

empty metal/wood seats & 
0.15 & 
0.19 & 
0.22 & 
0.39 & 
0.38 & 
0.30 \\ 

\hline
Wall Materials & 
    125 Hz & 
    250 Hz & 
    500 Hz & 
1000 Hz & 
2000 Hz & 
4000 Hz \\ \hline 


Brick: unglazed & 
0.03 & 
0.03 & 
0.03 & 
0.04 & 
0.05 & 
0.07 \\ 

Brick: unglazed \& painted & 
0.01 & 
0.01 & 
0.02 & 
0.02 & 
0.02 & 
0.03 \\ 

Concrete block - coarse & 
0.36 & 
0.44 & 
0.31 & 
0.29 & 
0.39 & 
0.25 \\ 

Concrete block - painted & 
0.10 & 
0.05 & 
0.06 & 
0.07 & 
0.09 & 
0.08 \\ 

Curtain: 10 oz/sq yd fabric molleton  & 
0.03 & 
0.04 & 
0.11 & 
0.17 & 
0.24 & 
0.35 \\ 

Curtain: 14 oz/sq yd fabric molleton & 
0.07 & 
0.31 & 
0.49 & 
0.75 & 
0.70 & 
0.60 \\ 

Curtain: 18 oz/sq yd fabric molleton & 
0.14 & 
0.35 & 
0.55 & 
0.72 & 
0.70 & 
0.65 \\ 

Fiberglass: 2'' 703 no airspace & 
0.22 & 
0.82 & 
0.99 & 
0.99 & 
0.99 & 
0.99 \\ 

Fiberglass: spray 5'' & 
0.05 & 
0.15 & 
0.45 & 
0.70 & 
0.80 & 
0.80 \\ 

Fiberglass: spray 1''  & 
0.16 & 
0.45 & 
0.70 & 
0.90 & 
0.90 & 
0.85 \\ 

Fiberglass: 2'' rolls & 
0.17 & 
0.55 & 
0.80 & 
0.90 & 
0.85 & 
0.80 \\ 

Foam: Sonex 2'' & 
0.06 & 
0.25 & 
0.56 & 
0.81 & 
0.90 & 
0.91 \\ 

Foam: SDG 3'' & 
0.24 & 
0.58 & 
0.67 & 
0.91 & 
0.96 & 
0.99 \\ 

Foam: SDG 4'' & 
0.33 & 
0.90 & 
0.84 & 
0.99 & 
0.98 & 
0.99 \\ 

Foam: polyur. 1'' & 
0.13 & 
0.22 & 
0.68 & 
1.00 & 
0.92 & 
0.97 \\ 

Foam: polyur. 1/2'' & 
0.09 & 
0.11 & 
0.22 & 
0.60 & 
0.88 & 
0.94 \\ 

Glass: 1/4'' plate large & 
0.18 & 
0.06 & 
0.04 & 
0.03 & 
0.02 & 
0.02 \\ 

Glass: window & 
0.35 & 
0.25 & 
0.18 & 
0.12 & 
0.07 & 
0.04 \\ 

Plaster: smooth on tile/brick & 
0.013 & 
0.015 & 
0.02 & 
0.03 & 
0.04 & 
0.05 \\ 

Plaster: rough on lath & 
0.02 & 
0.03 & 
0.04 & 
0.05 & 
0.04 & 
0.03 \\ 

Marble/Tile & 
0.01 & 
0.01 & 
0.01 & 
0.01 & 
0.02 & 
0.02 \\ 

Sheetrock 1/2"; 16"; on center & 
0.29 & 
0.10 & 
0.05 & 
0.04 & 
0.07 & 
0.09 \\ 

Wood: 3/8'' plywood panel & 
0.28 & 
0.22 & 
0.17 & 
0.09 & 
0.10 & 
0.11 \\  \hline

\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l | l | l | l |}
\hline
Ceiling Materials & 
    125 Hz & 
    250 Hz & 
    500 Hz & 
1000 Hz & 
2000 Hz & 
4000 Hz \\ \hline


Acoustic Tiles & 
0.05 & 
0.22 & 
0.52 & 
0.56 & 
0.45 & 
0.32 \\ 

Acoustic Ceiling Tiles & 
0.70 & 
0.66 & 
0.72 & 
0.92 & 
0.88 & 
0.75 \\ 

Fiberglass: 2'' 703 no airspace & 
0.22 & 
0.82 & 
0.99 & 
0.99 & 
0.99 & 
0.99 \\ 

Fiberglass: spray 5" & 
0.05 & 
0.15 & 
0.45 & 
0.70 & 
0.80 & 
0.80 \\ 

Fiberglass: spray 1"; & 
0.16 & 
0.45 & 
0.70 & 
0.90 & 
0.90 & 
0.85 \\ 

Fiberglass: 2'' rolls & 
0.17 & 
0.55 & 
0.80 & 
0.90 & 
0.85 & 
0.80 \\ 

wood & 
0.15 & 
0.11 & 
0.10 & 
0.07 & 
0.06 & 
0.07 \\ 

Foam: Sonex 2'' & 
0.06 & 
0.25 & 
0.56 & 
0.81 & 
0.90 & 
0.91 \\ 

Foam: SDG 3'' & 
0.24 & 
0.58 & 
0.67 & 
0.91 & 
0.96 & 
0.99 \\ 

Foam: SDG 4'' & 
0.33 & 
0.90 & 
0.84 & 
0.99 & 
0.98 & 
0.99 \\ 

Foam: polyur. 1'' & 
0.13 & 
0.22 & 
0.68 & 
1.00 & 
0.92 & 
0.97 \\ 

Foam: polyur. 1/2'' & 
0.09 & 
0.11 & 
0.22 & 
0.60 & 
0.88 & 
0.94 \\ 

Plaster: smooth on tile/brick & 
0.013 & 
0.015 & 
0.02 & 
0.03 & 
0.04 & 
0.05 \\ 

Plaster: rough on lath & 
0.02 & 
0.03 & 
0.04 & 
0.05 & 
0.04 & 
0.03 \\ 

Sheetrock 1/2'' 16"; on center  & 
0.29 & 
0.10 & 
0.05 & 
0.04 & 
0.07 & 
0.09 \\ 

Wood: 3/8"; plywood panel & 
0.28 & 
0.22 & 
0.17 & 
0.09 & 
0.10 & 
0.11 \\ 


\hline
Miscellaneous Material & 
    125 Hz & 
    250 Hz & 
    500 Hz & 
1000 Hz & 
2000 Hz & 
4000 Hz \\ \hline 


Water or ice surface & 
0.008 & 
0.008 & 
0.013 & 
0.015 & 
0.020 & 
0.025 \\ 

People (adults) & 
0.25 & 
0.35 & 
0.42 & 
0.46 & 
0.5 & 
0.5 \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
```

Comment: You will make life easier for yourself if you use a different inputformat (e.g. csv) and then typeset and plot from that. The `pgfplotstable` and `pgfplots` packages will easily allow you to do that. You can even use the tools from `pgfplotstable` to define the data inline and then plot using `addplot table <your data table>`;

Comment: I see. A .csv format would be easy to construct from the current table; that is, if I can supply the values of each bar horizontally, instead of vertically like @I_Like_To_Code showed in his example.

Comment: See command `\pgfplotstabletranspose` from the `pgfplotstable` package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a solution that does not do exactly what you want, but is extremely elegant in my admittedly biased opinion.

First, you put your data into a data file which is a text file. In my case, I named it `2014-01-01.txt`.

```
freq    conc    lino
125     0.01    0.02
250     0.01    0.03
500     0.015   0.03
1000    0.02    0.03
2000    0.02    0.03
4000    0.02    0.02
```

Next, you use [pgfplots](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?lang=en) to generate the plot, and [pgfplotstable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable?lang=en) to generate the table, both reading from the data file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\pgfplotstableset{% global config, for example in the preamble
  every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
  fixed,precision=2,
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  columns/freq/.style={column name=Frequency (Hz)},
  columns/conc/.style={column name=Concrete},
  columns/lino/.style={column name=Linoleum},
]{2014-01-01.txt}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Frequency (Hz)},
    ylabel=Absorption Coefficient,
    legend pos=south east,
    legend entries={Concrete,Linoleum},
    ]
  \addplot table [x=freq,y=conc] {2014-01-01.txt};
  \addplot table [x=freq,y=lino] {2014-01-01.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Edited**

The data file is now transposed so that each row corresponds to a material.

```
freq    125 250 500 1000    2000    4000
conc    0.01    0.01    0.015   0.02    0.02    0.02
lino    0.02    0.03    0.03    0.03    0.03    0.02
```

The code is similar except that we need to transpose the pgfplotstable object.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\pgfplotstableset{% global config, for example in the preamble
  every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
  fixed,precision=2,
}

\begin{document}    

\pgfplotstableread{2014-01-01-transpose.txt}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from={freq}]{\transposetable}{\loadedtable}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\loadedtable

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Frequency (Hz)},
    ylabel=Absorption Coefficient,
    legend pos=south east,
    legend entries={Concrete,Linoleum},
    ]
  \addplot table [x=colnames,y=conc] {\transposetable};
  \addplot table [x=colnames,y=lino] {\transposetable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: pgfplots seems like a great tool creating slick graphics. However, do you know if it is possible to supply the values for the different bars after one another, instead of side-to-side? Otherwise I'd still need to fully rewrite everything.

Comment: There are many ways to create a csv file. 1. The easiest way is to key in the values in the text file manually. 2. You could key in the values in a Google Spreadsheet and transpose it by following the instructions in http://gappstips.com/docs-tips/view/113/how-to-transpose-data-in-a-google-spreadsheet

Comment: `pgfplotstable` can also transpose tables - perhaps that would be a feasible improvement here?

Comment: Thanks Christian for the suggestion and for writing both `pgfplots` and `pgfplotstable`. I've implemented the transpose in the edited answer.

Comment: would you please update the link? [new link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgfplots/files/pgfplots/)

Comment: @ar2015 links updated to use CTAN links

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using the `S` column type from [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) for the table and [`pst-plot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-plot) for the plot.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[
%  locale = DE
]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{dataA.txt}
[[125,0.01],[250,0.01],[500,0.015],[1000,0.02],[2000,0.02],[4000,0.02]]
\end{filecontents*}
\readdata{\dataA}{dataA.txt}

\begin{filecontents*}{dataB.txt}
[[125,0.02],[250,0.03],[500,0.03],[1000,0.03],[2000,0.03],[4000,0.02]]
\end{filecontents*}
\readdata{\dataB}{dataB.txt}

\begin{document}

Table:

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format = 4]
  S[table-format = 1.3]
  S[table-format = 1.2]
}
  \toprule
   {Frequency} & {Concrete} & {Linoleum}\\
   {\si{\Hz}}  & {---}      & {---}     \\
  \midrule
    125 & 0.01  & 0.02\\
    250 & 0.01  & 0.03\\
    500 & 0.015 & 0.03\\
   1000 & 0.02  & 0.03\\
   2000 & 0.02  & 0.03\\
   4000 & 0.02  & 0.02\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Data plot:

\bigskip

\begin{pspicture}(-1.6,-1.2)(8.5,6.4)
  \psaxes[
    dx = 1,
    Dx = 500,
    dy = 1,
    Dy = 0.005,
%    comma
  ]{->}(0,0)(0,0)(8.5,6.4)
  \rput{0}(4.25,-1.0){Frequency~(\si{\Hz})}
  \rput{90}(-1.45,3.2){Absorption Coefficient}
 \psset{
   plotstyle = line,
   showpoints,
   dotstyle = o
 }
  \pstScalePoints(1,1){500 div}{200 mul}
  \listplot[fillcolor = red]{\dataA}
  \listplot[fillcolor = blue]{\dataB}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]